# Connect to mysql database on an online server

Tags: php, mysql

I recently bought a new domain and its hosting, it came with a control panel and mysql database. It is the mysql database which i want to use in conjunction with my website. i have created a sample database and a .php file to query and the echo the data but im am the getting the following error when i ran the php script. I dont know where i am going wrong.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1129] Host 'hostname' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

This is the database connection code

```
    <?php
class Database{
private static $dbName = 'mydatabase';
private static $dbHost = 'www.mydomain.co.zw';
private static $dbUsername = 'myusername';
private static $dbPassword = 'mypassword';

private static $cont = null;

public function __construct() {
    die('Init not allowed');
}
public static function connect(){
    //Open connection through the who;e application
    if(null == self::$cont){
        try {
            self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbPassword); 
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
    return self::$cont;
}
public static function disconnect(){
    self::$cont == null;
}
}
?>
```

This is the code i am using to query the database table

```
   <?php
    include 'database.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM test_table';
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($sql));
    $array = array();
    while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     array_push($array, $row);
    }
   $json = json_encode($array);
   echo $json;
   Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Comment: Please include the code that you're using to try to connect to the database.

Comment: I have added the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using localhost as the dbHost?

Comment: what good would that do? the mysql server is somewhere else, connecting to localhost would be utterly pointless.